# How to properly use blocks and threads in CUDA in C++ class

Tags: c++, cuda

I don't know if this is even possible with CUDA (I am new to CUDA programming). I want to have a kernel that does some work in parallel (`Test::work`) but some parts of this work can also be further parallelized (`stuff_that_can_be_done_in_parallel`).

In the example bellow (pseudocode), launching the kernel with `kernel<<<NBLOCKS,1>>>(d_test)` it works as expected, but I cannot find a way to do the further parallelization  by doing something like: `kernel<<<NBLOCKS,16>>>(d_test)` to process the shared_data with 16 threads within the block, 1 thread per item.

```cpp
class Test {
public:
    __host__ void set_data(int[] d) { ... }
    __host__ __device__ void work() {
        while (condition) {
            ... do some stuff sequentially, calculating x
            for (int i=0; i<16; i++) {
                stuff_that_can_be_done_in_parallel(i, x);
            }
            [synchronize]
            and update m_data with the values of shared_data
        }
    }
    __host__ __device__ void stuff_that_can_be_done_in_parallel(int i, int x) {
        ... calculate shared_data
    }

    int m_data[NELEMENTS];
    int shared_data[16]; // how to properly declare this as __shared__ ? 
};

__global__ void kernel(Test* t)
{
    t[blockIdx.x].work();
}


int main() 
{
    Test *h_test[NBLOCKS], *d_test;
    h_test = new Test[NBLOCKS]
    for (int i=0; i<NBLOCKS; i++) h_test[i].set_data(...);
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_test, NBLOCKS*sizeof(Test));
    cudaMemcpy(d_test, h_test, NBLOCKS*sizeof(Test), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);   
    kernel<<<NBLOCKS,1>>>(d_test);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    cudaMemcpy(h_test, d_test, NBLOCKS*sizeof(Test), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);   
    cudaFree(d_test);
    delete[] h_test;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: have a look at cuda samples. what you need is probably pipelining.

Comment: thanks, I will look at it

Comment: To declare `int shared_data` as `__shared__` you may need to use dynamic shared memory: https://devblogs.nvidia.com/using-shared-memory-cuda-cc/

Answer (score 2):

I found what I was looking for. It is a CUDA extension called 'CUDA dynamic parallelism'. Thank you all for your time and sorry for the unclear question. As I said, I'm very very new to CUDA programming and I didn't know at the time what I was really searching for.